# Restriciting access to my ASP.NET site based on existenence of client certificate

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, iis, iis-7, x509

I have an ASP.NET site which I would like to restrict access too. I have configured the server side certificate so all is well there, and I am readily able to issue client certificates to those third parties who I would like to access the site.

I would like the public site to function in the following way:

- User makes a request

  - If the user has a valid certificate, go ahead and load the page
  - Otherwise, either do nothing or return a Forbidden, etc..

So, it sounds simple enough. My question is what is the best practice way to do this? Should the client certificate be checked in the code, or is it more secure to do this on the IIS server itself?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks